# Link to meta in header?

Tags: feature-request

The link to meta seems to be gone in the new page header (effective 2013-12-05). Can it be added again? There seems to be space enough, now that the user name is replaced with the avatar.

Same with the link to "main" here on meta.

*edit*
(after mad scientist's answer). Alternatively, could meta, review and mod be combined in a pulldown menu, like for help?

Or, replace the link "recent achievements" with "meta"/"main". Recent achievements can quickly be accessed through the profile page, for which there's a link. If you're on meta there's absolutely no link to main, so it looks like I have to enter the URL in the URL bar. Not user friendly.

Comment: Must admit at first I thought the new bar sucked (it's been in beta on meta.so for a while) but it's grown on me a bit. You can swap between meta / main site on the drop-down arrow next to StackExchange.

Comment: I couldn't find how to get to meta easily either and came here to complain about it. I got here by clicking on my profile, then on "meta user", then on questions. It shouldn't be that circuitous, especially since that method only works if you previously contributed to meta. I liked the one click from before. The little icons that notify you of rep changes and messages are pointless because that information is available in your profile anyway, and that at least is still easy to get to.

Answer (score 1):

It already is in a pulldown menu:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

If you click the "Help" drop-down there is already a link to Meta.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually not that much space left in the new header, there are some elements that are not visible to some or even most users. Here's an example of the header on a different site for a moderator:

[image]

There is hardly enough space for another meta link here.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question.

Comment: So get rid of some of the silly fluff from the new banner and put the link to meta back.